# Twitter feed is showing blank in WP site

Tags: php, themes, feed, twitter

I am using themefuse WP theme and facing this problem.

http://themefuse.com/forum/thepractice-wp/twiiter-newsline-is-blank

Can someone please suggest if I need to use some other attribute. I am not finding any help on ThemeFuse site.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the username without the hash tag? look in your browser's javascript console for any errors. as-is this question is otherwise unanswerable and likely has nothing to do with WordPress specifically, and it's a premium theme so we can't see the code.

Comment: @Milo: Yes, I did remove the hash tag. It  still shows blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely because you are using the old Twitter API, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=4">
```

You will need to update your code to the new API:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USERNAME&include_rts=true&count=4&callback=twitterCallback2
```

This requires that you edit the code of the theme. Many themes suffered this issue for a few months ago when Twitter made their changes.