# New Twitter API and Twitter count + timeline doesn't work anymore

Tags: api, twitter

As some of you might know, Twitter has changed their API.

With that some of my plugins / codes stopped working.
I tried to fix them on my own, but failed.
I tried googling for the new API URL and I also searched here.
I tried to insert the URL provided in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99194/twitter-feed-is-showing-blank-in-wp-site), but once applied I only got an error message.

I need to update the following two codes with the new API, but don't know how to!

Twitter followers' count snippet:

```
function rarst_twitter_user( $username, $field, $display = false ) {
    $interval = 3600;
    $cache = get_option('rarst_twitter_user');
    $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.urlencode($username);

    if ( false == $cache )
        $cache = array();

    // if first time request add placeholder and force update
    if ( !isset( $cache[$username][$field] ) ) {
        $cache[$username][$field] = NULL;
        $cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = 0;
    }

    // if outdated
    if( $cache[$username]['lastcheck'] < (time()-$interval) ) {

        // holds decoded JSON data in memory
        static $memorycache;

        if ( isset($memorycache[$username]) ) {
            $data = $memorycache[$username];
        }
        else {
            $result = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_request($url));
            $data = json_decode( $result );
            if ( is_object($data) )
                $memorycache[$username] = $data;
        }

        if ( is_object($data) ) {
            // update all fields, known to be requested
            foreach ($cache[$username] as $key => $value)
                if( isset($data->$key) )
                    $cache[$username][$key] = $data->$key;

            $cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = time();
        }
        else {
            $cache[$username]['lastcheck'] = time()+60;
        }

        update_option( 'rarst_twitter_user', $cache );
    }

    if ( false != $display )
        echo $cache[$username][$field];
    return $cache[$username][$field];
```

Show latest tweets snippet:

```
function recentTweets($username, $number){ 
 include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php'); 

 $tweet = fetch_feed("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $number ); 

 if (!is_wp_error( $tweet ) ) : 
 $maxitems = $tweet->get_item_quantity($number);  
 $rss_items = $tweet->get_items(0, $maxitems);  
 endif; 

 if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No Tweets.</li>'; 
 else foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) { 

 $content = html_entity_decode($item->get_content()); 
 $link = html_entity_decode($item->get_permalink()); 
 $date = $item->get_date('U'); // retrives the tweets date and time in Unix Epoch terms
 $blogtime = current_time('U'); // retrives the current browser client date and time in Unix Epoch terms
 $dago = human_time_diff($date, $blogtime) . ' ago'; // calculates and outputs the time past in human readable format

 echo "<li>$content &#8226;<a href='$link'>$dago</a></li>"; 
 } 
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.
Here's [my blog](http://zoomingjapan.com) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

New Twitter API requires authentication, you need to go to [dev twitter](http://dev.twitter.com) and to create tokens. See [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

You need to use a library. I use [this one](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth)

**EDIT:**  You need to create an application on dev twitter (it's just a basic information, fulfill the form) and then you'll get access to your tokens. The library will manage connection to the API if you have those tokens.

I wrote a lot of articles about that but it's in French so I doubt you will read them and I'm not here to advertize. Probably a better idea to read articles from [this website](http://140dev.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sounds extremely complicated. First of all, I can't find anything about "tokens" at the website you linked to. Only about "Tweet cards" and other things, but no "tokens". The documentation also didn't answer this question. Could you elaborate a bit more for somebody who doesn't know much about how Twitter works in the background. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. I created an application and got my tokens. I also found a tutorial, but it only gives the code for creating a widget. I don't want that. I only want to know how I need to modify my old code to work with the new API.